# How to get iterator underlying type from iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator, decltype

This is a trivial question about `decltype`...
I have something like this:

```
using namespace std;
template< typename BIt >
void dostuff(BIt first, BIt middle, BIt last)
{
    auto temp = *first;
    for_each(first, middle, [](decltype((temp)) el)
    {cout << el << " "; });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi{11,22,33,44,1,2,3,4,5};
    dostuff(std::begin(vi), std::begin(vi) + 4, std::end(vi));
}
```

How do I avoid usage of *temp* variable(besides being ugly IDK if dereferencing `.begin`an  of an empty vector is legal :) )?

Comment: What's wrong with `decltype(*first)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB nothing... I need to get some sleep :)

Comment: btw after stack tracing my thought process... I remembered what I was wondering about... if I could get a iterator type underlying type from type, not the instance... now i see how dumb that was since decltype works on expressions. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for the (much more verbose, mind you) [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).

In particular, this resolves to `typename std::iterator_traits<BIt>::value_type`.

I don't think there's much benefit to using it though, it's more verbose and relies on an extra include, `<iterator>`. If you didn't want the temp variable you could very well just use `decltype(*first)`.